# How to adjust the height and width of background color in Highchart

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

I need to adjust the height and width of the background color of the "spline" highchart. I have set the color but its kind of going out of x and y axis.

chart: {
type: 'spline',
backgroundColor: '#F3F3F3',
alignTicks: false,
},

Comment: Could you, based on this simplified example, explain more precisely what you mean?
https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-kj1f1?file=/demo.jsx

Do you want to set the height and width of this chart?
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/design-and-style

Comment: The gray background color  should not go out of the x and y axis. I basically need to control the height and width on which i can set the background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the option you need:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.plotBackgroundColor?_ga=2.165692350.1083884187.1631103907-1968648769.1625472846
https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-m0w83

```
chart: {
    type: 'spline',
    plotBackgroundColor: '#FCFFC5'
}
```